# What is the insert overwrite work around in bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have already tried this:

```
update `cmi.sourav_test_bq_mg` b 
set b.name=a.name 
from `cmi.sourav_test_bq_mg_2` a 
where a.id=b.id
```

but it only worked for for rows where the condition matched, rather than for all of the every data. How can I updated all of it?

Comment: Insert overwrite? Do you mean an upsert or an update?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you can want to insert all data in a to b. If a row already exists in b, overwrite the name; otherwise just insert the row. Not sure you can do this with one single query. Delete rows in b that is also in a first, and insert all from a? Two queries.

Comment: can't we do it with one query?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/using-dml-with-partitioned-tables#using_a_constant_false_predicate_in_a_merge_condition

You can use `MERGE` statement instead of `INSERT OVERWRITE` statement, with constant false predicate.

```sql
MERGE INTO `cmi.sourav_test_bq_mg` a
USING (SELECT * FROM `cmi.sourav_test_bq_mg_2`) b
ON FALSE
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
 INSERT ROW
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
 DELETE
```

This query will delete all data in your destination table and insert every data from your source table.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use `MERGE` statement

```
MERGE cmi.sourav_test_bq_mg b 
  USING cmi.sourav_test_bq_mg_2 a 
  ON a.id=b.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET b.name=a.name 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT(id,name) VALUES (id,name)
```

Comment: merge only works on 1:1 data for a row in source and target, but insert overwrite doesn't have this limitation

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to HIVE Insert Overwrite, you can create a multi sql solution like

1. DELETE FROM Table or TRUNCATE
2. INSERT INTO TABLE `cmi.sourav_test_bq_mg` a select * from `cmi.sourav_test_bq_mg_2` [filtering logic]